# Can't get Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha5 Sass to compile using webpack

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, npm, sass

Apologies for posting a backtrace, but I wonder if someone could help me figure out what's wrong here.

I am using webpack to try and compile Bootstrap v4.0.0 alpha 5. However, it is failing with the following error:

```
ERROR in ./styles/main.scss
Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: 
  @each $breakpoint in map-keys($gutters) {
                      ^
      Argument `$map` of `map-keys($map)` must be a map

Backtrace:
    node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_grid.scss:50, in function `map-keys`
    node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_grid.scss:50, in mixin `make-row`
    assets/styles/common/_global.scss:15
      in /Library/WebServer/Documents/myproject/wp-content/themes/mytheme/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_grid.scss (line 50, column 24)
...
```

Rest of backtrace not shown.

I'm using the latest of everything - node 6.9.2, npm 4.0.3, latest modules as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at my own code in `_global.scss` which kicked off the problem, I was using Bootstrap's `make-row` mixin as follows:

```
$has-gutter-width: 1rem;

.row.has-gutter {
    @include make-row($has-gutter-width);
}
```

This doesn't work on Bootstrap v4.0.0 alpha 5. You need to pass a Sass "map" to the mixin for it to work, not a single value as it used to be on earlier versions of Bootstrap.

This map is a set of key-value pairs that set the gutter widths for different breakpoints. For the sake of simplicity I'll set the gutter width to the same value for each, but you can change it as you go:

```
$gutter: 1rem;

$has-gutter-width-map: (
  xs: $gutter,
  sm: $gutter,
  md: $gutter,
  lg: $gutter,
  xl: $gutter
)

.row.has-gutter {
    @include make-row($has-gutter-width-map);
}
```

That should sort it.